# Classic ASP - Detect line number and file from which a function is called?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Our application is made in good (?) ol' classic ASP. Not ideal but it works and it's pretty stable - has been for 10-15 years. It is not particularly well documented in places, such as where a 'translation' (client-controlled piece of text) appears. All we have against a translation is a clientid and translationid, neither of which are particularly helpful. I've tried searching the (10s of thousands of lines of) core code for `gettrans(1)` (translation 1) and can see that doing this for another 3100 is going to be a nightmare, not to mention inaccurate as there are many functions which are called with a transid passed into them, and then they call `gettrans(transid)`.

My last thought on this matter is the possibility that we could maybe detect, from `gettrans`, where a function is called from - not just the line number but the file name of the include (thankfully the includes are named usefully so figuring out where a translation is used should not be too hard!). I highly doubt that it would be possible to get the include name on the basis that includes are processed before ASP, but I'll settle for the overall filename and then we can combine the includes to get to the line of code and log the include file name.

I very much doubt this is possible and can't find anything on SO or Google. Does anyone know of any way to achieve this, or have any pointers on what I might try? Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Richard

Answer (score 0):

Most you can achieve is getting the currently executing script, which can be obtained by:

```
Dim currentPage
currentPage = Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")
```

When inside included page it will give you the "parent" page.

However getting "callee" information is not possible with classic ASP as far as I know, so you will have to add another parameter to the function being called then change all calls to pass the parameter in order to identify where it comes from. Looks like someone did something similar and called it [ASP Profiler](http://aspprofiler.sourceforge.net/), use it at your own risk of course. (Never tried myself)

Comment: Thanks @ShadowWizard, you've confirmed what I was dreading was the answer... I'll wait several more days, see if anyone has found a way to do this, and then accept your answer.